# "In preparation for" or "In Preparation of"?

Tags: word-usage, of-for

What´s the difference in use between "in preparation of" or "in preparation for"? They seem both correct.

Context:

> The team practiced how they would respond to bad weather in
>   preparation of Election Day.

Comment: *In preparation for* but *in anticipation of*.

Comment: With the exception of the usage @WS2 outlines below, preparation of sounds rather awkward.

Comment: Suggest migrating to English Language Learners

Answer (score 12):

It depends entirely on context, and is dictated by the meanings of the separate prepositions 'of' and 'for':

'I am making plans in preparation for my daughter's wedding' but; 'I haven't made the cake yet, I am still involved with preparation of the ingredients'.